# Not found comes out when laravel project moves to production server

Tags: php, laravel

When project is in local. This view can be seen from putting url "localhost/contact ". But 
When the project is in production server , "Not Found
The requested URL /contact was not found on this server." Is displayed.
How can I solve this problem. Thanks

```
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index')->name('contact.index');
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to many issues. I would suggest you to check whether your .htaccess is defined correctly and you have enabled mod_rewrite in your server. The method for this differs based on your server whether its Apache or Nginx. Follow the method suggested in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#pretty-urls) as in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of Documentation]

If you are using Apache server, don't forget to run the following commands to enable mod_rewrite and restart apache.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a laravel project in two ways.

1. php artisan serve (Development server)
2. using apache server (localhost/project_folder/public/)

if you are using 2nd method(apache) try this.

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo service apache2 restart